# pgAdmin III hangs while connecting with OpenERP

Tags: windows, postgresql, odoo

I created a test account on https://www.odoo.com/. After this I created a test company. To connect companies database, I downloading this application from given link. https://www.odoo.com/page/download

My problem is this, when I am trying to connect with OpenERP database, pgAdmin III got stuck. I am using windows 7 64bit. Please guide me where I am making some mistake.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you possibly running into a problem with a Windows or other firewall?  pgAdmin is stuck most likely because it is trying to connect but can't get a response .. does it eventually get a connection error?

Comment: Did you install OpenERP in your PC, or you have created a test database in OpenERP's server?